# i want to make my route wait to all the process to be done with nodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

i have a little complicated route which i want to modify what i get back from the database with mongoose
when it ends me the array of object of the items, each object contains an array of ID of another collection witch i have to add ass a new property to each object,
the code looks like this:

```
/* here i am trying to get the list of items */
let itemsList = await Items.find().lean();

/* now i want to loop through them to go to each ones inner array of IDs */
itemsList.forEach(item => {

    /* here i am making a new object property to containg what the IDs pointing at */
    item.theProducts = [];
            
    /* now i am going through the array of IDs */
    item.IDsArray.forEach(async product => {

        /* finding each product by the ID */
        let foundProduct = await SlemaniMaxzan.findById(product, { _id: 0, productName: 1, productPrice: 1 }).lean();
        /* showing the product */
        console.log(foundProduct);        

        /* now i am pushing it to the new property */
        item.theProducts.push(foundProduct);

    });
});

/* trying to check it the values has been added */
/* i expect the values has been added jsut fine, but it is not working */
console.log(itemsList);

res.render("mandubakan", { title: "list", mandubakan: itemsList });
```

when i run it, it has not been added and it just made a new empty array to the items but not added anything to it, and the program logs the itemsList even before loging each foundProduct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must avoid method `forEach` for asynchronous functions.

Try something like that:

```js
let itemsList = await Items.find().lean();

for (let item of itemsList) {
  item.theProducts = [];
  for (let product of item.IDsArray) {
    let foundProduct = await SlemaniMaxzan.findById(product, {
      _id: 0,
      productName: 1,
      productPrice: 1,
    }).lean();

    console.log(foundProduct);
    item.theProducts.push(foundProduct);
  }
}
console.log(itemsList);
res.render("mandubakan", { title: "list", mandubakan: itemsList });
```